# CSS/JQuery to place dropdown selector tick arrow before text

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to display the tick on dropdown before the text ??

```
SelectBox|v| <-- DROPDOWN WITH SELECTOR TICK AFTER TEXT

|v|SelectBox <-- I am trying to have a dropdwon like this
```

Please does anybody know how to do this with CSS or JQuery ?

Comment: Have you tried `direction:rtl;` ?

Comment: @BatuZet thankyou so much.. I had no idea about that.. And even I did not get any result in google regarding this ... Thanks you so much

Comment: @Deepanshu : That's Great ... BatuZet -> +1 UP. I just shared one of the plugin used by me in my previous project to solve the multiple selection of values from one select box.

Comment: @BatuZet is there any way to change the color of tick also using css only

Comment: @Deepanshu i dont think this is possible with pure `select` unless you fake it with `div`s or `ul`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Thanks to @Batu Zet

I never thought the answer would be so simple. Just need to add `**direction:rtl;**` to the style of my dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chosen plugin and it will provide a lot of flexibility.

[CHOSEN PLUGIN](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

**Right to Left Support**

Chosen supports right to left select boxes too. just add "chosen-rtl" in addition to "chosen-select" to your select tags and you are good to go.

```
<select class="chosen-select chosen-rtl">
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I just the solution.. all thanks to BatuZet direction:rtl;

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hRx2R/6/)**.

You want something like this??

```
  var source = [
      "Affogato",
      "Americano",
      "Bicerin",
      "Breve",
      "Café Bombón",
      "Café au lait"];
  // Create a jqxDropDownList
  $("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList({
      source: source,
      selectedIndex: 3,
      theme: 'energyblue',
      checkboxes:true
});
$('#jqxDropDownList').jqxDropDownList({selectionRenderer: function () 
{
         return "Please Choose:";
}
});
```